# what is the difference between a(i,:) and [a] in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, vector, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to use the following code:

```
for i = 1:n
    a(i, :) = f(x,y,l);
    j = g(x,y,a(i,:);
end
```

`g` is a function that does matrix multiplication of `x` and `a(i:,)` and subtracts it with y, to get delta.
I get error when it is `a(i:,)` and no error if I just try `[a]`.

Comment: Two comments. First, you're missing a parenthesis at the end of your definition of `j`. Second, without knowing exactly what the error message is or how `f` and `g` are defined, it is difficult to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: `[a]` ia exactly the same as just `a` whereas `a(i,:)` is only the `i`th row of `a`

Answer (score 0):

by `a(i,:)` you mean that take the ith row and all the columns of the ith row of matrix a

for example lets suppose we have a `3x3` matrix a

```
>> a = magic(3)

a =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> a(1,:)
```

will give us the first row of the matrix a

```
ans =

     8     1    6
```

which will result in a one dimensional array , when you send 'a' you send the whole 2 dimensional array in the input , you are getting an error probably because of dimension mismatch probably 
what you can try is check

```
[rowa , colb] =  size(a(i,:))
```

and

```
[rowx , colx] = size(x)
```

because for matrix mutiplication the dimensions should be `nxm` `mxn` or else you cannot mutiply two matrices or maybe the resulting error from multiplcation has not the same dimensions as y, becasue subtration is element by element